# Do not release tableview cell when UITableview scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have fixed number of cells in `UITableView` and all cells contain the `UITextField`. When I have focus on textfield and scroll the table view application crashed Because I am reading the value of text field when editing ends. After scroll cell released. So can any one tell me how I prevent the cell from release.

Comment: Are u using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method?

Comment: Yes. I am using this.

Comment: I suggest u to go with @shraddha hattimare. But if u have any problem with UIScrollView than you have to make do some tricky programming without dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method.

Comment: If you still want to use UITableview then you can maintain array of UITextfield values. And set the value of textfield from array in cellForRowAtIndexpath. When you update textfield value also replace new textfield value in array

Answer (score 0):

Without code I can not suggest your that where you was wrong but I suggest you that the best way is put `self.tblView.scrollEnabled = NO;` when your keyBoard is open and also put `self.tblView.scrollEnabled = YES;` when your keyboard is hide.

Answer (score 0):

if you have fixed number of cell and all table cell contain text field, then it is better to use scroll view instead of table view

Comment: You mean tableview in scrollview?

Comment: no, instead of tableview , use scrollview and keep text field in scroll view.

Answer (score -1):

You can resign that textfield on scrollViewDidScroll: delegate.

Comment: You are getting error when it calls textfielddidendedit delegate after releasing the textfield. isnt it ? So this method will call textfielddidendedit when you start scrolling tableview before releasing tablecell.